# How do you input from a text file that contains multiple datatypes

Tags: java, file, input, types

Java newbie here, I have a problem that I have been banging my head on the wall for several hours now.

Basically, I need to read a text file that contains String, Integer, and Double datatypes.  (see below for the file)

The text is formatted in two lines. The first line is only the product name, and the second line is an integer representing the factory number, and then 4 decimals that represent the sales in one of four factories in millions of dollars.

```
CrossTrainMax
1 15.1 12.8 3.14 2.3
AirGlider
3 12.2 4.6 6.5 8.3
AquaWalker
2 3.82 1.75 7.6 6.38
SuperHike
1 9 11.2 7.5 8.4
```

The first value is the name of a product.  The single digit integer is a factory number where it is produced.  The decimal number are the sales of that product in millions of dollars, delimited by a white space.

My plan is to read in the product name as a string, and then use the integer value as a SWITCH statement.
(The % of profit is different at each factory, so I thought the best way to go about solving this way to calculate the total profit inside the switch statement.)

After I get the total sales per product, I will then have to display to the user which product has the highest sales.

So my questions are:

a)  How can I read in multiple data types if I am trying to do it line by line using NextLine?
  I know how to read in all integers, all doubles, or all strings, but what is the best way to go about it if they are all different?

My attempt so far has resulted in mismatch exceptions.

b)  Am I better off reading all of the values in as strings and using regular expressions to parse them into variables?

c)  If I am going to be sorting the Sales based on the highest profit, will I need to store each products total sales in a separate variable?  Is it possible to do this if I am reading in the input of the file using loops?  (We have not covered arrays yet)

Here is the beginning of the code I have been playing with.  I am still stuck on the problem of reading the separate data types in.  Any feedback/ criticism is appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner; // Needed for scanner class
import java.io.*; // Needed for the File and IOException

public class SalesProcessor
 {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
   {
   int x;
   double sales = 0;
   double total = 0;
   double profit = 0;



    // Create scanner object for keyboard input.
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the filename: ");
    String filename = keyboard.nextLine();

    // Open the file
    File file = new File(filename);
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
    String line = inputFile.nextLine( );

    for (x = 1; x <= 5; x++)

      { 

  while (line != "END")
   {
    int plant = inputFile.nextInt();

      switch (plant)
       {
       case 1:

       while (inputFile.hasNext())
        {
        sales = inputFile.nextDouble();
        total = total + sales;



        }
        profit = sales * .06;
        System.out.println(total);
        System.out.println(profit);
        System.out.println(profit);
       break;
       }



    } 
   }

  }
 }
```

Comment: Your while loop seems to go 'till the end of file. It will throw exception when it encounters the string after the last double (and /n) for a given line.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you need to use the java tokenizer per a friend.